# Scope of Variable values across webjob instance in Azure

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I have a Service Bus Queue listened by web job. As we want the requests to be processed faster, we have increased the web job instances (say 3). But when there is any error in processing, we do not want to pick the other messages from the queue. To achieve this, we are setting up a variable as 0. My doubt is , will the value of this variable be 0 across all the instances or the value is specific to the instance.

The code going like this...

```
int webJobStatus = 1;

while(webJobStatus == 1)
{
    try
    { 
       //processing....
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       webJobStatus = 1; // in case of exception, value is set as 0.
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each instance of the WebJob will have its own instance and therefor its own value of webJobStatus. This means setting the webJobStatus in a specific instance only stops the processing of that specific instance and not that of the others.

**Possible solution**
One possible solution to have all instances respond to such a value, would be to look into having something like a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) in a database, Azure Storage or something like that. This way you're centralizing the value that controls the WebJob flow.
Please keep in mind that this will have a performance penalty.

**My two cents**
Don't completely stop processing messages when an exception occurs. Since you're building for the cloud, exceptions *will* occur. Resources might be (very) temporarily unavailable, messages could hold incorrect data, all of which can cause issues. Think about adding telemetry and logging to your webjob (Application Insights) to help find and fix issues fast. By enabling a dead-letter queue, when processing a message fails multiple times (default: 10) it will be put on the dead-letter queue. Use that as a basis for fixing any issues and reprocessing failed messages.
Also see: [Poison message handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/poison-message-handling) and [Overview of Service Bus dead-letter queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues)

**By the way**
I'm guessing the assignment in the catch block should be `webJobStatus = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm maintaining a value in database as well. And that happens each time there comes an exception. Yes, webJobStatus is set as 0 in catch block as well. Also I do not want the message to be pushed to dead letter queue. So I'll increase the defaultdeliverycount.